# Efficient sampling of discrete random variable

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, random

Suppose that *X* takes value *i* with probability *p(i)*, where *i = 0, ..., k - 1*, for some *k*. The probabilities are rational numbers *a(i)/b* where it is safe to assume *b < 1 000 000* (but maybe not *b < 100 000*) and *k <= 10*.

What would be the most efficient algorithm for sampling? The number of samples is around *b*, i.e., high.

I can come up with two not completely satisfying approaches:

1. Construct the list *c = [p(0), p(0) + p(1), ... , p(0) + ... + p(k - 1), 1.5]*
2. Generate uniformly distributed random number *p* and return *i*, such that *c[i] <= p < c[i + 1]*.

The second step is logarithmic in *k* (bisection). Can we do better? Sure:

1. Construct the list *c = [0, ... , 0, 1, ... , 1, ...... , k - 1, ... , k - 1]*, where the number of occurrences of *i* is proportional to *p(i)*.
2. Generate uniformly distributed random number *p* and return *c[floor(length(c) * p)]*.

The second step now takes constant time, but computation may take too much space.

(This will be implemented in Python3, if this information matters.)

Comment: See Vose's "alias" method:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method

Comment: @TimPeters Thank you; I marked my question as a duplicate now ...